# Searching CStrings in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, string, search, cstring

I was wondering if there is a native C++ (or STL/Boost) function which will search a CString for a specified string?

e.g.

```
CString strIn = "Test number 1";
CString strQuery = "num";

bool fRet = SomeFn(strIn, StrQuery);

if( fRet == true )
{
  // Ok strQuery was found in strIn
 ...
```

I have found a small number of functions like CompareNoCase IndexOf etc... but so far they don't really do what I want them to do (or use CLR/.Net)

Thanks!

Comment: Please be aware that `CString` is not actually a standard class in the C++ standard.

Comment: I'm actually stunned by the fact that you didn't just look for the obvious function names "find" or "search" in CString or std::string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[CString::Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms928981.aspx) is what you want, one of the overloads does sub-string searching.

```
CString strIn = "test number 1";
int index = strIn.Find("num");
if (index != -1)
    // ok, found
```

Answer (score 2):

[string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [CString::Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314323(VS.60).aspx)?

It's not STL or boost but since you have two CString's it seems the most reasonable method to use.